# Simplest OpenCL program fails

Tags: opencl, intel, gpu, fedora-26

I am using an `Dell` Laptop with an `i3` processor and an `Intel` 5500 series graphics card.

```
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$ lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$
```

The kernel:

```
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$ uname -r
4.13.4-200.fc26.x86_64
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$
```

I have the simplest `OpenCL` program running on `Fedora` 26.

```
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$ cat /etc/fedora-release
Fedora release 26 (Twenty Six)
```

I installed the `Linux` [driver][1] from `Intel`.

```
#include <iostream>

//#define __NO_STD_VECTOR // Use cl::vector instead of STL version
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS

#ifdef __APPLE__
//#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#include <OpenCL/cl.hpp> /* read cpp_wrapper_fix.txt */
#else
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#endif


int main(int, char**)
{
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
}
```

The `Makefile` is very simple:

```
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$ more Makefile 
UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)
# -std=c++11 -Wall -march=native
ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
CXX=g++
CPPFLAGS=-O3
LDFLAGS=-O3
LDLIBS=-lOpenCL
endif

ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Darwin)
CXX=clang++
CPPFLAGS=-O3
LDFLAGS=-O3
LDLIBS=-framework OpenCL
endif

RM=rm -f

SRCS=device_query.cpp
OBJS=device_query.o
EXEC=device_query

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$
```

When I run it, it shows:

```
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$ ./device_query 
X server found. dri2 connection failed!
```

I am not sure why this is failing.

```
    [idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$ ls -l /dev/dri/
    total 0
    drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root        80 Oct  5 11:10 by-path
    crw-rw----+ 1 root video 226,   0 Oct  5 11:10 card0
    crw-rw----+ 1 root video 226, 128 Oct  5 11:10 renderD128
    [idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$
```

This is the output of `clinfo`

```
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$ sudo clinfo
[sudo] password for idf: 
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
Number of platforms                               4
  Platform Name                                   Portable Computing Language
  Platform Vendor                                 The pocl project
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 pocl 0.14, LLVM 4.0.0
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             POCL

  Platform Name                                   Experimental OpenCL 2.1 CPU Only Platform
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel(R) Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.1 LINUX
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer 
  Platform Host timer resolution                  1ns
  Platform Extensions function suffix             INTEL

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 beignet 1.4
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short cl_intel_media_block_io cl_intel_planar_yuv cl_khr_gl_sharing
  Platform Extensions function suffix             Intel
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 

  Platform Name                                   Clover
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 17.1.7
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA

  Platform Name                                   Portable Computing Language
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     pthread-Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz
  Device Vendor                                   GenuineIntel
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 2.0 pocl HSTR: pthread-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-haswell
  Driver Version                                  0.14
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 2.0
  Device Type                                     CPU, Default
  Device Available                                Yes
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               4
  Max clock frequency                             2000MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     4
    Supported partition types                     equally, by counts
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             4096x4096x4096
  Max work group size                             4096
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Preferred work group size multiple              8
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 16      
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 2 / 2       
    half                                                 8 / 8        (n/a)
    float                                                4 / 4       
    double                                               2 / 2        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              18879172608 (17.58GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           18879172608 (17.58GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Shared Virtual Memory (SVM) capabilities        (core)
    Coarse-grained buffer sharing                 Yes
    Fine-grained buffer sharing                   Yes
    Fine-grained system sharing                   No
    Atomics                                       Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Preferred alignment for atomics                 
    SVM                                           0 bytes
    Global                                        0 bytes
    Local                                         0 bytes
  Max size for global variable                    0
  Preferred total size of global vars             0
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        32768 (32KiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            1179948288 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             32768x32768 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                128
    Max number of read/write image args           128
  Max number of pipe args                         16
  Max active pipe reservations                    1
  Max pipe packet size                            1024
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               18879172608 (17.58GiB)
  Max constant buffer size                        18879172608 (17.58GiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties (on host)                      
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Queue properties (on device)                    
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Preferred size                                16384 (16KiB)
    Max size                                      262144 (256KiB)
  Max queues on device                            1
  Max events on device                            1024
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
    SPIR versions                                 1.2
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_spir cl_khr_int64 cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics

  Platform Name                                   Experimental OpenCL 2.1 CPU Only Platform
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 2.1 (Build 10)
  Driver Version                                  1.2.0.10
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 2.0 
  Device Type                                     CPU
  Device Available                                Yes
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               4
  Max clock frequency                             2000MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     4
    Supported partition types                     by counts, equally, by names (Intel)
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             8192x8192x8192
  Max work group size                             8192
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Preferred work group size multiple              128
  Max sub-groups per work group                   1
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 32      
    short                                                1 / 16      
    int                                                  1 / 8       
    long                                                 1 / 4       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 8       
    double                                               1 / 4        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              16731688960 (15.58GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           4182922240 (3.896GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Shared Virtual Memory (SVM) capabilities        (core)
    Coarse-grained buffer sharing                 Yes
    Fine-grained buffer sharing                   Yes
    Fine-grained system sharing                   Yes
    Atomics                                       Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Preferred alignment for atomics                 
    SVM                                           64 bytes
    Global                                        64 bytes
    Local                                         0 bytes
  Max size for global variable                    65536 (64KiB)
  Preferred total size of global vars             65536 (64KiB)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        262144 (256KiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             480
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            261432640 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   64 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          64 bytes
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 480
    Max number of write image args                480
    Max number of read/write image args           480
  Max number of pipe args                         16
  Max active pipe reservations                    65535
  Max pipe packet size                            1024
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max constant buffer size                        131072 (128KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     480
  Max size of kernel argument                     3840 (3.75KiB)
  Queue properties (on host)                      
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Local thread execution (Intel)                Yes
  Queue properties (on device)                    
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Preferred size                                4294967295 (4GiB)
    Max size                                      4294967295 (4GiB)
  Max queues on device                            4294967295
  Max events on device                            4294967295
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
    Sub-group independent forward progress        No
    IL version                                    SPIR-V_1.0
    SPIR versions                                 1.2
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer 

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
Number of devices                                 1
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 BroadWell U-Processor GT2
  Device Vendor                                   Intel
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.4
  Driver Version                                  1.4
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 beignet 1.4
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Available                                Yes
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               23
  Max clock frequency                             1000MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     1
    Supported partition types                     None, None, None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             512x512x512
  Max work group size                             512
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
  Preferred work group size multiple              16
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 8       
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 2 / 2       
    half                                                 0 / 8        (cl_khr_fp16)
    float                                                4 / 4       
    double                                               0 / 2        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (cl_khr_fp16)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             No
    Round to nearest                              No
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    32, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              4294967296 (4GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           2147483648 (2GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        8192 (8KiB)
  Global Memory cache line size                   64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            65536 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   4096 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          1 bytes
    Max 2D image size                             8192x8192 pixels
    Max planar YUV image size                     8192x8192 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             8192x8192x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                8
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               65536 (64KiB)
  Max constant buffer size                        134217728 (128MiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      80ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
    SPIR versions                                 1.2
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                __cl_copy_region_align4;__cl_copy_region_align16;__cl_copy_region_unalign_same_offset;__cl_copy_region_unalign_dst_offset;__cl_copy_region_unalign_src_offset;__cl_copy_buffer_rect;__cl_copy_buffer_rect_align4;__cl_copy_image_1d_to_1d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_2d;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_2d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_3d;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_3d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_buffer;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_buffer_align4;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_buffer_align16;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_buffer;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_buffer_align4;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_buffer_align16;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_2d;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_2d_align4;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_2d_align16;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_3d;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_3d_align4;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_3d_align16;__cl_copy_image_1d_array_to_1d_array;__cl_copy_image_2d_array_to_2d_array;__cl_copy_image_2d_array_to_2d;__cl_copy_image_2d_array_to_3d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_2d_array;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_2d_array;__cl_fill_region_unalign;__cl_fill_region_align2;__cl_fill_region_align4;__cl_fill_region_align8_2;__cl_fill_region_align8_4;__cl_fill_region_align8_8;__cl_fill_region_align8_16;__cl_fill_region_align128;__cl_fill_image_1d;__cl_fill_image_1d_array;__cl_fill_image_2d;__cl_fill_image_2d_array;__cl_fill_image_3d;
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_spir cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short cl_intel_media_block_io cl_intel_planar_yuv cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_fp16

  Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              Success [POCL]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No platform
    NOTE:   your OpenCL library only supports OpenCL 2.0,
        but some installed platforms support OpenCL 2.1.
        Programs using 2.1 features may crash
        or behave unexepectedly
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$ sudo ./device_query 
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$
```

Output of

```
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$ gcc -v
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2) (GCC) 
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$ 

[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$ ldd ./device_query
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe77d28000)
    libOpenCL.so.1 => /lib64/libOpenCL.so.1 (0x00007f5527874000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f55274eb000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f55271d5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5526fbe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5526bed000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f55269e9000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /lib64/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f55267de000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f55265d6000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5527a7c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f55263b7000)
[idf@localhost OpenCLDeviceQuery]$
```

Comment: What is the output of `clinfo`?

Comment: @Zindarod See the end of the OP for the output of clinfo.  I did not realize that existed. I installed clinfo (along other seemingly useful tools) with sudo dnf install opencl-filesystem opencl-utils  clinfo clpeak ocl-icd mesa-libGL mesa-libGL-devel

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo clinfo`?

Comment: @Zindarod  I modified the OP to be sudo clinfo

Comment: I don't see any problem in the output of `clinfo`. What is the output of `ldd ./device_query`?

Comment: @Zindarod I modified the OP for ldd ./device_query

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion: The opencl-icd or a driver you use has problems with being called from within a Wayland session. Log out and select the Xorg session.

Comment: That works!  BTW, instructions on disabling Wayland: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/96134/how-can-i-set-xorg-as-a-default-on-fedora-25/